# Add values from HTML into PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I'm trying to take content submitted from an HTML form and plug it into the PHP file that I have as the action. The PHP code supplied below is a small snippet of the entire code which can be found at the bottom of this page: https://www.activecampaign.com/api/example.php?call=contact_add

HTML Form

```
<form method="POST" action="/acform.php">

<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" placeholder="email address"></div>
<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="name"></div>
<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="lname" placeholder="name"></div>
<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="phone" inputmode="tel"></div>
<div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary submit-btn" class="_submit" type="submit">Submit</button></div>

</form>
```

PHP File

```
$post = array(
    'email'                    => '**Need "email" value here**',
    'first_name'               => '**Need "fname" value here**',
    'last_name'                => '**Need "lname" value here**',
    'phone'                    => '**Need "phone" value here**',
```

Comment: Why not just use `$_POST`?

Comment: In you acform.php file you should have <?php var_dump( $_POST ); ?> What does the output show?

Comment: @jeff
var_dump output: Array ( [email] => test@gmail.com [fname] => John [lname] => Smith [phone] => 1234567890 )

Comment: @JosephSible I tried <?php echo $_POST["email"]?> but the output is empty/blank

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<form method="POST" action="/acform.php">
<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" placeholder="email address"></div>
<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="name"></div>
<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="lname" placeholder="name"></div>
<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="phone" inputmode="tel"></div>
<div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary submit-btn" name="submit" class="_submit" type="submit">Submit</button></div>

</form>

//acform.php
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$array = array(
    'email' => $_POST['email'],
    'first_name' => $_POST['fname'],
    'last_name' => $_POST['lname'],
    'phone' => $_POST['phone']
);

}

?>
```